# What am I misunderstanding regarding Android TTS onInitListener?

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I have a class meant to transcribe text to audio files. I want to reuse the class and the TTS engine to speed things up:

```
public class TtsToFile implements TextToSpeech.OnInitListener {

    private TextToSpeech mTts;
    private boolean initDone = false;

    public TtsToFile() {
        mTts = new TextToSpeech(Globals.context, this); // context, listener
        while (!initDone) try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return;
    }
    public void transcribe(String speech, String fileOutPath) {
        HashMap<String, String> myHashRender = new HashMap();
        myHashRender.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID, speech);
        mTts.synthesizeToFile(speech, myHashRender, fileOutPath);
        while (mTts.isSpeaking()) try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mTts.stop();
        return;
    }

    @Override
    public void onInit(int status) {
        initDone = true;
        return;
    }
    public void finish() {
        mTts.shutdown();
        return;
    }
}
```

I call the class like so:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Globals.context = this;
        Log.d("a", "a");
        TtsToFile ttf = new TtsToFile();
        Log.d("a", "b");
        ttf.transcribe("hello world", new File(Globals.sdDir, "test.wav").getAbsolutePath());
        Log.d("a", "c");
        ttf.finish();
        Log.d("a", "d");
        finish();
    }
```

Yet in LogCat, only "a" is being printed. What am I misunderstanding here? It looks like the class never finishes instantiating and just keeps sleeping. It never reads initDone as true... I think. LogCat shows no crash.

Comment: looks like a crash. logcat output?

Comment: No, it looks like the class never finishes instantiating and just keeps sleeping. It never reads initDone as true... I think. LogCat shows no crash.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear about that from the start.